# converting .eps file to .gif - size issue

Tags: image, gif, postscript, eps

I've been trying to convert some .eps files to .gif. The .eps files are pretty wide. When I use ps2img to convert them the .gif files which are produced contain only part of the image. The same problem occurs when I use 'xv' to open the .eps file and try to save it as a .jpg. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/)?

```
convert your.eps new.gif
```